# Javascript - passing data to a function without parentheses

Tags: javascript, function, variables, call

I know similar questions have been asked, but I still can't get this quite right.  In this code, after 3 seconds, a message appears saying you can click the box.  When you click it, an alert appears. That's what I want.   Notice the function call has no parantheses.  If you add the parentheses like this `onclick=myfuction()` it doesn't wait for the click.  It just displays the alert.  What if I wanted to pass a value to that function, if I try to do `onclick=myfuction("somedata")`  It won't wait for the click. Is there a way to pass data to the function in this situation?

```js
setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('okmessage').style.display='block',
document.getElementById('mydiv').onclick=myfunction,
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.cursor='pointer'},3000);

function myfunction() {alert("hello world")}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv" style="width:300px;height:100px;background:red"></div>
<div id="okmessage" style="display:none">click the box now</div>
```

Comment: Sure, use closures :)

Comment: I'm not that good with javascript, I'll need an example.

Comment: @CheeseFlavored Change onClick code to   `document.getElementById('mydiv').onclick=function() {
    myfunction('somedata')
  }` and make your function to accept new param as, `function myfunction(data) { alert(data); }`

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for !   That worked.   Thank you